# Google Drive search function not searching correctly within documents

Tags: search, google-drive

I have a folder in my Google Drive with just one document called "links". This document contains just the following text:

```
java 5 enums enumerations full version
```

When I type "enunms" [sic] in the search box, I get my "links" file as a search result, and a correct suggestion that says «Did you mean "enums"?». However, if I type "enumerations", I get no results.

Why is that and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to fix this issue. This is directly tied to the Google Drive search function which is out of our power to change. The "Did you mean" feature usually is meant to correct spelling mistakes/typos, not suggest alternative versions of a word.

In conclusion, it is not possible to fix this issue.

Comment: I think the question was why the word enumerations, which *is* in the file, is not being found.